# setInterval/setTimeout problem getting messages at once

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

i got a part of code that should send message in discord every x second but it awaits x seconds and sends all messages at once

```
let amount = 5;
let interval = 3000
for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  setInterval(() => {
    message.channel.send($arr[Random(0, $arr.length)]);
  }, interval);
}
```

I tried this outside the loop , with setTimeout() and clearInterval() or clearTimeout() it never worked

**EDIT:**

```
let amount = 5;
const interval = 300; // 3000
const tId = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(amount)
  // message.channel.send($arr[Random(0, $arr.length)]);
  if (--amount === 0) clearTimeout(tId);
}, interval);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the CPU a breather

```js
let amount = 5;
const interval = 300; // 3000
const tId = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(amount)
  // message.channel.send($arr[Random(0, $arr.length)]);
  if (--amount === 0) clearTimeout(tId);
}, interval);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a function and call it within itself in the `setTimeout` (instead of `setInterval`), and use counter instead of the `for` loop.
What happens in your code: all the `setInterval` inner code is executed at once...

Try something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
var amount = 5;
var interval = 3000

function msg() {
  message.channel.send($arr[Random(0, $arr.length)]);
  counter++;
  if(counter<amount) {
    setTimeout(msg, interval);
  }
)

msg();
```

Comment: @Karan, thank you!  I overlooked that...  Corrected my answer.